# TR-8 as master clock for eurorack system

Tags: midi, clock

I am trying to clock my eurorack with my TR-8. I have a 2-hp MIDI to CV/gate, which I feed with the MIDI out of my TR-8 (using a MIDI-to-USB cable as the 2-hp takes USB mini as input). I tried changing the MIDI channels on the TR-8, but it didn't change.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had seached the internet enough before asking this question, but apparently not. [Here](https://modwiggler.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=202111) is the answer: I need a MIDI host to convert the MIDI from the TR-8 to USB-MIDI read by the 2hp MIDI to CV/gate.